# Difference between enumerate(iterable) and zip(itertools.count(), iterable)

Tags: python, python-itertools

While

```
list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

has to load the list in memory,

```
list(zip(itertools.count(), ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

generates the elements one at-a-time. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: No, they both do exactly the same. Why do you suppose that?

Comment: not yet very well versed in Python :)

Comment: `enumerate` and `zip` are both iterators. They will generate items one by one when requested. Using `list` around an iterator forces it to generate all it can in order to build the list.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do `list(some_iterable)`, you are loading the contents of this iterable in memory in a list.

The following

```py
def integer(x):
    print("Generating", x)
    return int(x)

print("[1]")
iterable = (integer(x) for x in range(10, 20))

print("[2]")
contents = list(iterable)

print("[3]")
for value in contents:
    print(value)
```

will output

```
[1]
[2]
Generating 10
Generating 11
Generating 12
Generating 13
Generating 14
Generating 15
Generating 16
Generating 17
Generating 18
Generating 19
[3]
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

(Note that all elements are generated *before* the for-loop).

The following

```py
def integer(x):
    print("Generating", x)
    return int(x)

print("[1]")
iterable = (integer(x) for x in range(10, 20))

print("[2]")
contents = iterable

print("[3]")
for value in contents:
    print(value)
```

will output

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
Generating 10
10
Generating 11
11
Generating 12
12
Generating 13
13
Generating 14
14
Generating 15
15
Generating 16
16
Generating 17
17
Generating 18
18
Generating 19
19
```

(Note that all elements are generated *during* the for-loop.)

`enumerate` is an iterator, as well `zip` and `itertools.count`.